# Look for Max in function

Tags: functions, roots

I need to show that the follwing function has just got a minimum and no maximum. I know what it looks like and it is pretty obvious but i can't find a way to explain. The question implicates we might not even have to calculate something -.-

$$ \frac{\exp(x^2)}{(11+10 \sin(x))} $$

I already derived it. Then it looks like this:

$$ \exp(x^2)\cdot\left(\frac{2x}{11+10\sin(x)}-\frac{10\cos(x)}{(11+10\sin(x))^2}\right) $$

But i can't manage to equate with zero :/ and thus get it's root...

Thanks in advance and pls excuse my english :-)